# Calculate mean over columns using double for-loops

Tags: python, for-loop

I have the following table

```
import pandas as pd
full_data=pd.read_csv('candy-data.csv')
full_data.head(5)
```

Giving me this [image: output table]

I am now attempting to create a table that lists the mean winpercent value of each column from chocolate to pluribus for which I attempted to do a double for-loop. It looks as follows:

```
categories=["chocolate", "fruity", "caramel", "peanutyalmondy","nougat","crispedricewaver","hard","bar","pluribus"]
def Value(valuename):
    for i in range(len(categories)):
        print("Average of "+str(valuename)+": "+round(statistics.mean(full_data[full_data[valuename]==1].iloc[:,-1])))
        for m in categories:
            Value(m)
```

As you can see, I am attempting to let each element of the categories list run through the entire process (i.e. break down full_data dataframe to where the value of the element equals to 1, take the last column where winpercent is, return the winpercent means of this list and insert/return the sentence "Average of ELEMENT: WINPERCENT_MEAN_ELEMENT).

However, running this code leads to result at all. Can anyone please explain to me what I did wrong and/or how to properly set up my code?

Comment: You call the function Value in function itself which is incorrect. I will come back with a solution
In the meantime, it would help if you could add some sample of your data, for test purposes

Comment: Thanks!

The csv can be downloaded here: 

https://github.com/fivethirtyeight/data/tree/master/candy-power-ranking

Or is there a better way how to provide a data sample here in stackoverflow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
import numpy as np
categories=["chocolate", "fruity", "caramel", "peanutyalmondy","nougat","crispedricewaver","hard","bar","pluribus"]

d={i: np.mean(full_data[full_data[i]==1]['winpercent']) for i in categories}
```

Comment: it says "TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed". Any idea what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Just change crispedricewaver to crispedricewafer in categories

Answer (score 0):

You can try this snippet of code:

```
categories=["chocolate", "fruity", "caramel", "peanutyalmondy","nougat","crispedricewaver","hard","bar","pluribus"]

def getMean(columnName):
  for c in categories:
    print("Average of {0}: {1}".format(c, df[df[c]==1][columnName].mean()))
getMean("winpercent")
```

Comment: I needed to indent the for-loop but after that, it works! Thanks a lot!